# What should our documentation contain?

Tags: discussion

Of [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) we seem to have at least touched on the others, but I don't think we have asked this one yet.

The question "What should our documentation contain?" is number two on the list linked above which includes some helpful links.

What should our documentation contain?

Comment: How do you edit that for starters?

Comment: For you discuss what changes are appropriate, someone with elivated powers can make the changes.

Answer (score 3):

Most importantly, the documentation should contain a concise discussion of what questions can and cannot be asked on this site. I'm making this answer a community wiki, so feel free to add to it.

If some of the types of questions listed as on-topic or off-topic are debatable, please open a meta discussion for each one.

Questions about the following topics are considered **on-topic**:

- Tools, materials, or techniques used in woodworking.

  - Tools may be general types of tools or specific products, including the tools themselves, as well as jigs, fixtures, safety gear, and tool accessories. Software that is used in the design of woodworking projects, such as SketchUp or AutoCAD, may also be considered a tool.
  - Materials may include any materials commonly used in woodworking projects, including wood, composite materials, hardware, fasteners, and supplies such as sandpaper and glue. Questions about materials may also include questions about selecting materials appropriate to the project and *general* advice on how to locate and purchase said materials.
  - Techniques may apply to any phase of a woodworking project, including design, prototyping, cutting, construction, finishing, safety, and fixing mistakes.
- Properties of a type of wood
- Design considerations for a general type of project (e.g., "What factors do I need to consider when designing a chair?")

  - Joinery recommendations for load-bearing components
  - Human factors (e.g.,  appropriate dimensions and proportions for a chair)

Questions about the following topics are considered **off-topic**:

- Help identifying a particular piece of wood (for example, by looking at a picture)
- Product or vendor recommendations
- Help finding woodworking plans
- Critiques of a specific woodworking project or design (not to be confused with *general* design considerations)

Comment: Nice job getting this started, @rob